# How to rename a file by adding a prefix to two timestamps?

Tags: windows, command-line, rename

I have several sets of files, all named `12-34-567 - 12-34-567.ext`, so basically a timestamp followed by a space, a hyphen, a space, another timestamp, and the extension.

When I try to rename them in command prompt by issueing the command
`ren *.* "Prefix - *.*"`
they are all renamed to `Prefix - - 12-34-567.ext`.

Why is the first timestamp removed, and how can I do the rename properly so they are renamed `Prefix - 12-34-567 - 12-34-567.ext`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to solve the problem with PowerShell:

```
dir | Rename-Item -NewName { "Prefix - " + $_.Name }
```

If you stuck in the old cmd world, try the following:

```
for %filename in (*.*) do ren "%filename" "Prefix - %filename"
```

Comment: I hate PowerShell with a passion, but the command option works like a charm.
I've accepted your answer because it solved my question, but I still don't understand why rename gets it wrong and drops the first timestamp. If anyone knows, I'd really like to hear it.